# How can I get out of the loop and continue the loop again?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I want to write a program to do the task bellow:

---

I have an array of integers,

I, as user, give an integer *s* (as in word *search*),

I want it to do a linear search and find the *s* in the array,

There may be more than one cell containing desired *s*,

The code should start from cell 0, search, find *s* in, say, *n_th* cell,

Show *n* in the output,

Then get out of the loop and go to another part of program to a *label*

Then get back in loop searching cells from *n+1_th* cell to the end.

I did this with *goto label* but is there any other ways I can do so?

Comment: @Kiarash is right: What OP wants is essentially a way of having iterator coroutines in C++ (see Python, C#, …).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can be done. But first, I want to show you the simple and elegant solution:

```
std::vector<int> v = {....};
int to_search = ...;

for (auto elem : v)
{
  if (e == to_search)
  {
     // do something
  }
}
```

Are you sure this isn't what you actually need?

---

Now to your actually requirements:

```
template <class It, class T>
It find_next(It begin, It end, T to_search)
{
   for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it)
   {
      if (*it == to_search)
        return it;
   }
   return end;
}
```

```
std::vector<int> v = {....};
int to_search = ...;

auto it = v.begin();

while ((it = find_next(it, v.end(), to_search)) != v.end())
{
   // do something with *it
}
```

---

You you really want to use indexes, that can be easily adapted:

```
int find_next(const std::vector<int>& v, int begin, int end, int to_search)
{
   for (int i = begin; i != end; ++i)
   {
      if (v[i] == to_search)
        return i;
   }
   return end;
}
```

```
std::vector<int> v = {....};
int to_search = ...;

int from = 0;

while ((from = find_next(v, from, v.size(), to_search)) != v.size())
{
   // do something with v[from]
}
```

---

now if you really want raw loops and not functions, that can of course be also done:

```
std::vector<int> v = {....};
int to_search = ...;

int from = 0;

while (true)
{
   for (; from < v.size(); ++from)
   {
     if (v[from] == to_search)
       break;
   }

   if (from == v.size())
      break;

   // do something with v[from]
}
```

---

I hope you can see that each iteration I presented to you gets more complicated to basically do the same thing.

So I would really reconsider if the first one I showed you isn't what you want.

---

*disclaimer*: not compiled, not tested

Comment: You have a typo: it should be `v.end()`, not `it.end()` in the `while` condition

Comment: Have I made a mistake?  Very possible, I kinda rushed it. If not, I am interested to know why you don't like this answer. @SingerOfTheFall ty, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Examples of two approaches, assuming that it's the index you're interested in.

Calling a function when an element is found:

```
void search(const std::vector<int>& v, int x, std::function<void(int)> index_handler)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (v[i] == x)
        {
            index_handler(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Letting the caller determine the starting point (like `std::string::find`):

```
int search_2(const std::vector<int>& v, int x, int start)
{
    for (int i = start; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (v[i] == x)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Example use:

```
int main()
{
    // Method 1
    std::vector<int> vs = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3};
    search(vs, 2, [](int i) { std::cout << "found at index " << i << '\n'; });

    // Method 2
    int index = search_2(vs, 2, 0);
    while (index >= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "found at index " << index << '\n';
        index = search_2(vs, 2, index + 1);
    }
}
```

The second method is more flexible, but also messier and more error-prone.